# Real Analysis, Integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Prove that if $f:\left[a,b \right]\rightarrow\mathbb R $ is integrable, then ${f}_{+},{f}_{-}:\left[a,b \right]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ given by 
>   $$f_+(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> f(x),\hspace{1em}&f(x)\ge0\\
> 0,\hspace{1em}&f(x)<0
> \end{cases}$$
>   $$f_-(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0,\hspace{1em}&f(x)\ge0\\
> -f(x),\hspace{1em}&f(x)<0
> \end{cases}$$
>   are both integrable.

My doubt is how it shows that the oscillation of ${f}_{+} \leq f(x)$ and ${f}_{-} \leq f(x)$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's given that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are integrable? If so, notice that $f=f_++f_-$ and the sum of two integrable functions is again integrable.

Comment: @Mathematician42, it's the opposite way: it's given that $f$ is integrable and shall be shown that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are integrable.

Comment: @md2perpe: The question has been edited, this was not clear the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean Riemann integrable. In this case if your function is continuous:

**Lemma 1**: On any interval $\sup f_+ - \inf f_+  \le \sup f - \inf f$

**Proof**: On an interval, suppose $\sup f \ge 0, \inf f \ge 0$. Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem,  $f \ge 0$ on the interval such that $f_+ = f$.
Suppose now that $\sup f \ge 0, \inf f \le 0$. Then by the IVT, there is a point $x$ in the interval where $f(x) = 0$. We deduce that $\inf f_+ = 0$. Furthermore, $\sup f_+ = \sup f$. The conclusion follows. Now suppose $\sup f \le 0, \inf f \le 0$. Then by the IVT, $f_+ = 0$ on that interval such that 
$\sup f - \inf f \ge 0 =  \sup f - \inf$.

Let $P$ denote a partition of $[a,b]$, $P = \{x_0 = a,x_1, \dots,x_n = b \}$ and let $M_i$ (resp. $m_i$) be the maximum (resp minimum) value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[x_{i}, x_{i+1}]$.

Then

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists P, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M_i \Delta x_i - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_i \Delta x_i < \epsilon  $$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_i - m_i) \Delta x_i < \epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]} f_+ -\inf_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]} f_+) \Delta x_i \le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_i - m_i) \Delta x_i < \epsilon$$

Therefore $f_+$ is integrable. The proof is analogous for $f_-$.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously $f_\pm \geq 0$ and $|f| = f_+ + f_-$, so 
$$0 \leq f_\pm \leq f_+ + f_- = |f|$$
and therefore
$$0 \leq \int f_\pm \leq \int |f| < \infty$$
Thus, $f_\pm$ is integrable.